# Trying to pass variables from JS to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass these variables via AJAX POST method from my JS file to my PHP file, but nothing goes thru. The console log is clean, and the table in the php page loaded, but the fields are empty. The idea is to set the variables in JS & then pass them into the php file to be displayed in the table.

Here's a [Screenshot of the Chrome Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVqNu.png)

Here's the .JS part:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test-php.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
      min: "D201522170",
      invoice: 60,
      sum: 60, // Replace with dynamic radio button values
      descr: "Food Regime",
      exp_date: "31.12.2018"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
  });
```

And here's the .PHP part:

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
}
$min        = $_POST['min'];
$invoice    = $_POST['invoice'];
$sum        = $_POST['sum'];
$exp_date   = $_POST['exp_date'];
$descr      = $_POST['descr'];

$data = <<<DATA
MIN={$min}
INVOICE={$invoice}
AMOUNT={$sum}
EXP_TIME={$exp_date}
DESCR={$descr}
DATA;
```

These variables are displayed on the screen in a table:

```
      <table class="striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Merchant Id</td>
            <td> {$min}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Invoice Number</td>
            <td>{$invoice}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Product Description</td>
            <td>{$descr}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Payment</td>
            <td>{$sum}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Total Amount</td>
            <td>{$sum}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>
          </tbody>
          </table>
?>
```

Comment: in your .js part you try to call jquery ajax function inside php tags

Comment: "Here's the .JS part:"....and yet it's enclosed in `<?php` tags....where are your `<script>` tags?

Comment: <?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
} is supposed to be in the php part, my bad :)

Comment: @Pok3rPrinc3 edit the question and post correct

Comment: Ok, so then..."nothing goes through" is not an error message or problem statement. Have you used your browser's Developer Tools to try and debug the AJAX call? Is it sent? Is the data in the body correct? What status is returned? Are there any console errors? What about in PHP - how you are verifying that the $_POST data is not what you expected? You haven't given us any clear detail. I note you appear to have included the "success" callback within the data object itself, which I guess is a mistake. It may or may not be the cause of your problem, but without more info it's hard to be certain.

Comment: Your ajax call is correct and should work - check the developer console for errors and the network tab, if something is sent to the server and to the correct url

Comment: @Philipp there's a missing closing bracket on `data:{}`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile no, it isn't.. the only wrong thing is, that success is inside data

Comment: @ADyson I've reworded the question (i think) placed the php tag in the right place, and added some more explanation & a screenshot. I dont get any errors in the log other than the favicon.ico not found.

Comment: I don't see any calls to "test-php.php" in your console output... And also even once you get that working, there's no way that any data will be displayed anywhere, because in your `success` function all you do is log the returned data into the console. Do you understand how AJAX works? once you get the response you have to _do something with it_ . e.g. if the response to the ajax contains some HTML, then you'd need to add it to your page - simplest example: `$("body").append(data);` would append the result to the bottom of your current page.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your help sir, i'll look into it. Any idea why it's working so i can look into that specifically ?

Comment: Also as we said, your "success" function is in the wrong place, so first thing you need to do is move it as per Fathma's answer...so that jQuery will actually run that code when the ajax returns. Then secondly you need to add some code to make JavaScript append your response data into your page, as I've mentioned above

Answer (score 4):

success function should be out side the data

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "test-php.php",
dataType: "text",
data: {
  min: "D201522170",
  invoice: 60,
  sum: 60, // Replace with dynamic radio button values
  descr: "Food Regime",
  exp_date: "31.12.2018"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  });
```